# Package Babel Error in Lyx

Tags: latex, lyx

I am new user Lyx. I just installed, Version LyX  2.1.4. After creating my first file, I run the DVI viewer, but I get this error:

> You need to specify a language, either as a global option or as an
>   optional argument to the \usepackage command; You shouldn't try to
>   proceed from here, type x to quit.

I don't know how to set the language. My OS is Windows 10. Help please.

Comment: please start a new question at tex.stackexchange.com and please include a minimal example. Please read here for more information: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the babel package, you need to specify which language should be used, for example:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

The square brackets are used for optional arguments. In this case you need to give the language so that babel knows how to work.

Another way is to specify it as a global option, which can be placed as an optional argument in the document class, but since I only know this solution in in LaTeX, I can't give you an example for this.

UPDATE:

If I get it right, you can simply write it anywhere in the preamble like this:

```
\language english
```

just look up what language you need and insert it for `english` or `ngerman`

Comment: Thank you Krazy Kalle for you response, but where exactly I have to make these modifications?

Comment: The second alternative can be written anywhere in the header after preamble, so between `\begin_header` and `\end_header`, but after `\end_preamble`. The first one needs to be in the preamble, between `\begin_preamble` and `\end_preamble`. Maybe I could help more specific if you edit your question and write some code. And you should do a tutorial first.